# Delphi how to split non delimiter string to stringlist

Tags: string, delphi, split

split/explode strings with delimiter is common and easy way but i couldn't find anyway to split strings without delimiter.

How can i split this string to a stringlist or an array?

```
THISISTESTRINGWITHOUTANYDELIMITERORCOMMAORSPACE
```

What i want to split to;

```
T H I S I S T H E S T R I N G W I T H O U T A N Y D E L I M I T E R  O  R C O M M A O R S P A C E
```

First of all sorry to everyone who tries to help me, my question wasn't contain so much information and i deserved negative votes.

What i'm trying to do is trying the parse a data comes from an cnc machine as txt format.

That machine sends job details (coordinates, duration, material type etc.) toan txt file, but it's an old machine and sending data as below;

```
"D4MAH96708F41H52X90"
```

and there is an software which providing by manufacturer, when you load the data to that program it decodes the data shows you duration, material type, heat, coordinates and so on, but to do so you need to enter data to software as letters one by one (damn me if i know why), i thought i can create an small exe file to split this string to letters as;

```
D
4
M
A
H
9
6
```

and send to cnc's decoding program through RS232 it'll save time to the operator because sometimes output data is very large. But i couldn't make it because there was no delimiter on the data.

Comment: Your question fails to specify *how* you want to split the string. Do you want to split it in same-size blocks (like THI, SIS, TES, TRI, NGW, ...), or do you want to split it on every vowel (TH, IS, IST, ESTR, INGW, ITH, O, UR, AN, ...), or do you want to split it according to English words in the Oxford English Dictionary (THIS, IS, TEST, RING, ...) or some other dictionary? In the last case, greedily or lazily?

Comment: And as your example shows - any typos ("WITHOUR" instead of "WITHOUT") in string will make it almost impossible to split or at least will produce very wrong or messy results. Very curios how you come up to that task/question?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand you are right sorry about that, edited the question.

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev just asking for curiosity, why typos are important, is there a function that understand the meaning of the string?

Comment: @BMF: So you want the result to be a string equal to the input, but with a space between each character? Or do you want to produce an array or string list containing the characters?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand well, the string im working on is nıt including any understabdale words it's like "AXCFGBHGKLSDKJSDKJSAHJKDHASJKDHJKASH" so i don't think it's related to any kind of dictionary.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand exactly, comma or space or any kind of delimiter

Comment: @BMF the typos were important because initially I understand your goal to split the string by English words. Just initial question and example were misleading.

Comment: @BMF: Your input is a string. Do you want the output to be an array of characters or a string? In the first case, there's no such thing as "comma or space or any kind of delimiter"...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand why did you deleted your answer?

Comment: Because it seems like you want the output to be an array, not a string. My answer returns a string.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand 
yeah but when i convert that string to delimiter version then i can parse and save to a stringlist or an array, what i can't do is convert string to delimiter one. I mean if i can add space or comma between letters then i can split it, your answer were solving my issue

Comment: @BMF: But that's horribly inefficient. A Delphi string *is*, under the hood, an array of characters. It is trivial to iterate over these. So it is very unnecessary to create a new string (char array) with intertwined spaces, and then create a string list/array from that (just a different kind of char array), and iterate over this one.

Comment: It's like translating a book in the 500th century from Latin to English: You can let a monk simply translate the Latin book A into a new book B in English. It is entirely unnecessary to first copy A into a new Latin book A1, and then copy that one into a new Latin book A2, and then copy that one into a new Latin book A3, and then translate that one into a new book B in English...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand i couldn't explain better, you are absolutely right, but that is the only solution i can think of,in this case machine is too old, it's system works this way, new one is so much expensive and i need to find a solution for it.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to split the string into single characters stored in a string list?

```
for var ch: Char in inputstring do 
  list.Add(ch);
```

BTW, the string actually can be treated directly as an array of char.

Comment: "the string actually can be treated directly as an array of char." how? is it like str:='MYSTRING' -- showmesssage(str[0]) ?

Comment: @BMF: Yes, but strings use 1-based indexing.

Comment: Actually, in most cases, the true answer here is the second part ("BTW"). But it seems like the OP would rather want a string as output, and not an array at all...

Comment: A zero-based access to the characters in a string S can be done like `S.Chars[0]`

Comment: @UweRaabe i didn't know that, thanks for teaching me this way.